# How do I pass a pointer to an integer to ioctl in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ioctl

I am trying to use V4L2 (video for Linux) via python.

One of the examples in the V4L2 documentation is this:

```c
int index;

index = 0;

if (-1 == ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_INPUT, &index)) {
    perror("VIDIOC_S_INPUT");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I have tried translating it into python:

```py
from fcntl import ioctl
import v4l2

with open('/dev/video0') as cam:
  index = 0

  if -1 == ioctl(cam, v4l2.VIDIOC_S_INPUT, index):
    print('failed')
  else:
    print('success', index)
```

When I run that I get the error

> OSError: [Error 14] Bad address

I know it's not the camera because I can successfully call VIDIOC_ENUMINPUT, and get the name of the camera.

I understand that the issue is that I'm passing `index`, which is an integer and not a pointer, so how can pass in a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use types provided in the v4l2 library

If I change

```py
index = 0
```

To

```py
index = v4l2.c_int(0)
```

Then the code works.